# How to copy an entire database with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The purpose of this task is to copy my database that contains the default values for all entities into a new created database. This task will be called when the program creates the database for the first time, so the newly created database would be filled with the values from my default value database.

The problem with just copy and paste database is that my default value database has messy primary keys. The value of each entity's primary key are not in order.

What I want is to create new database for the program, with the values copied from another database but with continuous primary key for each entity (1,2,3,4,5 no jumping).

The requirement is that the structure, references from the default value database has to remain the solid. For example when copied that entity A reset to id=1 from 5, then all the references changed to 1 as well.

How can I achieve this? Is there a fast way to do it instead of manually copying each entities? Because it is quite a large database.

Note: The default database context is identical to the newly created database context.

Comment: i think no straight forward  you have to use some etl tool to change id (continuous primary key for each entity) and map then correctly .

Comment: If you want to get a copy for whole database (not particular tables), you can just copy and attach database files or backup and restore database (or use some utility to copy database).

Answer (score 0):

I my self done such a task few months back.There is no automatic way.You must do it manually.I would like to share the steps where I have used.

**Step 1 :**

I have created a new db (i.e. `Migrated`) by initialling (`delete data` and `PK Reseed`) the old db.After that I have an exact copy of the old db (i.e. schema only.No data)

*Here is the script for one table*

```
Use Migrated;
GO

delete from IpOccupantNotes
GO

--To Reseed the PK

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[IpOccupantNotes]', RESEED, 0) 
GO
```

**Step 2 :**

After that I have inserted the relevant data from the old db (`Legacy` in my case) as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[IpOccupantNotes] (Name, ZipCode)
select  a.Name,a.ZipCode from [Legacy].[dbo].[IpOccupantNotes] as a;

GO
```

**Note :** If you have any question,feel free to ask.I'll help to you :)